# Dropdown list in Twitter Bootstrap in tablet and smartphones

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have just started working with twitter bootstrap and I'm having a problem with it's drop down menu.

Menu items in drop down don't seem to work in tablets and smartphone, even the one shown in the example here: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/carousel.html

If you visit that example in a smartphone and click on the collapsed drop down menu and click on 'Dropdown' and then click on an item like 'Action' or 'Another action', it won't work. But if you visit that page in a laptop or desktop computer and reduce the size of the browser to the size of a tablet or smartphone, then those items work fine.

Can someone please tell me what is wrong here? Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't see what you mean it won't work when the link for Action and Another action is "#" .Can you further explain it?

Comment: yeah, normally if u click on it, it will lead to say: index.html#, which is what happens when u view it in a laptop or pc, which is when u actually 'click it'. But when u 'touch' Action or Another action, nothing happens and the dropdown just shuts up.

Comment: what about if you bind some event on the dropdown list.